# JavaScript: filling an array with form field

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I am attempting to fill and parse an array using JavaScript and an HTML form element.  The following test produces the expected result ("Test1 Test2 Test3" renders in the destination div).  Here's the working test code:

```
<div>
    <span id="put-stuff-here"></span>
    <span id="put-stuff-here2"></span>
    <span id="put-stuff-here3"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var itemSelected = { 'fields': [ 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3' ] }
    document.getElementById('put-stuff-here').innerHTML = itemSelected.fields[0];
    document.getElementById('put-stuff-here2').innerHTML = itemSelected.fields[1];
    document.getElementById('put-stuff-here3').innerHTML = itemSelected.fields[2];      
    })
</script>
```

However, when I attempt to define the variable "itemSelected" using a form field, nothing renders in the destination div.  Here is the non-working code:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <select id="getItem">
            <option value="{ 'fields': [ 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3' ] }">ItemName</option>
            <option value="{ 'fields': [ 'Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6' ] }">ItemName2</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <span id="put-stuff-here"></span>
    <span id="put-stuff-here2"></span>
    <span id="put-stuff-here3"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#getItem").change(function () {
        var itemSelected = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById('put-stuff-here').innerHTML = itemSelected.fields[0];
        document.getElementById('put-stuff-here2').innerHTML = itemSelected.fields[1];
        document.getElementById('put-stuff-here3').innerHTML = itemSelected.fields[2];      
    })
    .change();
</script>
```

For some reason the value passed to "itemSelected" doesn't get processed as an array.  I'm hoping someone here will be kind enough to take a look and perhaps suggest a solution.

Thanks,

-Michael

Comment: The value assigned to `itemSelected` doesn't get processed as an array because it's a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value coming from your form is a string, which is why it's not doing what you want it to do. I'd suggest changing your form values:

```
<select id="getItem">
  <option value="Test1,Test2,Test3">ItemName</option>
  <option value="Test4,Test5,Test6">ItemName2</option>
</select>
```

Then modify your event handler:

```
var itemSelected = $(this).val().split(',');
```

That'll give you your array. That's assuming `fields` is just a means to an end, if you still really need it for other reasons, just assign your array to `itemSelected.fields` of course.

Comment: Thank you, ultranaut, your response solved my problem!  I appreciate the super-fast response.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it doesn't work is because the value of the `select` is a `string` and not a `object` 
you can use `jQuery.parseJSON` to turn it back into a object.

change 
`var itemSelected = $(this).val();`
to 
`var itemSelected = $.parseJSON($(this).val());`

Comment: Thank you, Josh, for the tip.